# Correct method for Patio deck attachment to roof

Tags: deck, patio

Just moved into a house, the patio deck roof looks unstable. It's connected to the rafters by what looks like deck nails with no ledger board. Looking for opinions in this condition if I should tear the whole thing down and restart, or if it's a fixable solution. What materials do I require to repair and make the roof safe ? Is this acceptable with CA building standards ? Thank you in advance.

[image: img3]
[image: img4]

Comment: what do you mean by patio deck roof?  is it a roof extension or is there a deck above it. ?  confusing wording but i suppose you mean a roof extension that is over a deck?   Simpson joist hangers if it just a roof extension.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I meant to say its a roof extension over a deck.

Comment: One question: does it 'look unstable' or 'is unstable'? What makes you feel/define that unstability? The attachment itself look ok, but it may be the spatial structure stiffness that's making that impression. If this is the case, you need stifners (not sure if I'm using a proper word) for the whole structure.

Answer (score 1):

The normal fascia board has been removed and a 2X put on the end of the rafters to support the roof. Depending on the length I have seen this done and last for many years.
I would think if it was not up to code the home inspection would have identified that since it  looks new. It looks like they nailed through the boards. You could add hanger's if you are concerned [like this](http://www.fastenersplus.com/Simpson-LUS210-2x10-Face-Mount-Hanger-G90-Galvanized?gclid=CNmqj6zZ1c4CFUZhfgod_NcJGQ). I would not tear it off unless a real problem is raised other than "looks unstable" or has leakage problems.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and unfortunately I did not have a home inspection prior to purchase otherwise I would have lost the house. Looks as though hangers are the best route to take.

Comment: I guess that's a good answet.What concerns me, however, is 'instability' mentioned in the question. I put my comment under the question.